# Showing custom badge or text on Azure DevOps Pipeline Summary Page

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

I have a requiement where I need to show custom badge or some kind of custom message somewhere on summary page (Pipelines -> Select Build -> Summary Page) of Azure DevOps build Pipeline based on code coverage or unit test or static code analysis.
Is it possible to customize summary page of build? I checked few links which suggest we cann't custmize summary page but create some extenions.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options for adding information to the build results page that you could explore depending on the depth of information you'd like to display.

Option 1 - add a tag to the build to indicate some type of status.  This can be done manually or [programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#addbuildtag-add-a-tag-to-the-build) (using a logging command) as part of the build itself which could contain additional logic and evaulations/conditions before adding a tag.  Badges *do* appear at the top of the build results page and will show across all tabs.

Option 2 - as you did mention, extensions allow you to customize results and even show additional tabs and information on the build results page. There is a sample extension called [Build Results Enhancer](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer) that can help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can create programmatically Markdown file containing your summary, saving in a temporary `.md` file and use special logging command. See Powershell example:

```
$summaryTempFilePath = "$PSScriptRoot/summary.md"
"My Summary" | Out-File $summaryTempFilePath
Write-Host "##vso[task.uploadsummary]${summaryTempFilePath}"
```

Then your summary can be viewed in build summary page under "Extensions" tab.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#uploadsummary-add-some-markdown-content-to-the-build-summary